# INSERT INTO onto a joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to add some registers on a combination of two tables made through **JOIN**, *in a single SQL instruction*.

Is it possible? How could I do it? 
And how would it be, if I need an "upsert" operation, instead of a simple INSERT?

It is a PostgreSQL server (if it matters...). My first approach was trying to use a **WITH..AS**, which did not help:

```
WITH tableX (field1, field2)
    AS (
    SELECT fruits.apple, pets.dog
    FROM fruits fr JOIN pets pt on fr.key = pt.key
    )
    INSERT INTO tableX (field1, field2) VALUES (9999999, 999);
```

As a result, a sound **ERROR: "tableX" doesn´t exist**.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you just looking for `UNION`?

Comment: No, no... I would like to insert registers on two tables simultaneously and was wondering if it could be possible through some sort of trick since they're joinable.

Comment: In your example you only have a table and you cant insert into a CTE. Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously doubt you can do that.  If you create the table ahead of time you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO tableX 
SELECT fruits.apple, pets.dog
    FROM fruits fr JOIN pets pt on fr.key = pt.key
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE tableX (field1 ..whatever data types..., field2) 
SELECT fruits.apple, pets.dog
    FROM fruits fr JOIN pets pt on fr.key = pt.key
```

Comment: Thank you @OldProgrammer ! Gonna review my idea, here.